# How to flatten array in object

Tags: typescript

I'm going to develop with react and type script.
This is my data.
The types of 1 depth item and 2 depth item are the same

```js
[
  {
      id: "item1",
      name: "foo",
      subCategories: [
          {
              id: "item1-1",
              name: "bar1",
          },
          {
              id: "item1-2",
              name: "bar2",
          }
      ]
  },
]
```

I want to flatten to object like this.

```js
[
  {
      id: "item1",
      name: "foo",
      subCategories: [...]
  },
  {
      id: "item1-1",
      name: "bar1-1",
  },
  {
      id: "item1-2",
      name: "bar1-2",
  },
  ...
]
```

Please tell me how to convert the array.

Comment: Hi, first of all I understand your problem and it depends in a few things, for example, will just be 1 depth to work with or will it need to be recursive? What have you tried to fix the issue? Provide a little more in terms of what you tried to fix it and what use-cases will this be applied. Without this the question will most likely be closed, see this documentation and try to add the answer to the questions I made. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `reduce` method but aware of `subCategories` is not defined in some values

```
const array= [
  {
      id: "item1",
      name: "foo",
      subCategories: [
          {
              id: "item1-1",
              name: "bar1",
          },
          {
              id: "item1-2",
              name: "bar2",
          }
      ]
  },
]

const result = array.reduce((c,data)=>{
  c.push({...data});
  c.push(...data.subCategories)
  return c;
},[]);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it recursively, something like this:

```
type Item = {
id: string;
name: string;
subCategories?: Item[];
};

function flattenItems(items: Item[]): Item[] {
const result: Item[] = [];

for (const item of items) {
 result.push({ id: item.id, name: item.name });

 if (item.subCategories) {
   result.push(...flattenItems(item.subCategories));
 }
}

return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap

```js
const array= [
  {
      id: "item1",
      name: "foo",
      subCategories: [
          {
              id: "item1-1",
              name: "bar1",
          },
          {
              id: "item1-2",
              name: "bar2",
          }
      ]
  },
].flatMap((obj) => [...obj.subCategories, obj]);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can write a function to return the desired result.

```
const data = [
  {
      id: "item1",
      name: "foo",
      subCategories: [
          {
              id: "item1-1",
              name: "bar1",
          },
          {
              id: "item1-2",
              name: "bar2",
          }
      ]
  },
];

const newData = [data[0], ...data[0].subCategories];
```

If your data can have multiple objects then please modify your question. Will update my answer with a more generic approach like creating a function

Comment: That what I mentioned in the answer. If the data will be multiple in the upper array then let me know